# JSON Object Key with Quotes in them - How?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a list of names and am using them as keys to a json object, however, sometimes, the key might contain double quotes in them, like so:

```
var parts = {
    Expando Sleeve 1/4": [
    {
        id:"45", name:"TEST REPORT", partID:"4"
    },
    {
        id:"15", name:"01-077512", partID:"4"
    }]
};
```

So, the problem I'm facing here is I have the name as `Expando Sleeve 1/4"` which is what I need it to be, but I have it stored inside a hidden input element on the page like so: `<input type="hidden" value="Expando Sleeve 1/4"" name="partName" />`

So I do an ajax call, than use the value of the hidden input element... like so to add response values to a global `parts` array...

```
var $val = $('input[name="partName"]').val();

if (!parts.hasOwnProperty($val))
    parts[$val] = [];

parts[$val].push(response[$val]);
```

The problem here is that it adds the key into the json object `parts` like so:

`parts[Expando Sleeve 1/4\"]` instead of parts`[Expando Sleeve 1/4"]`.  So I'm struggling on how to unescape the double quote in here and have the key set like this:  `Expando Sleeve 1/4"`.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a double quote HTML character `&quot;` in the JSON.

```
var parts = {
    "Expando Sleeve 1/4&quot;": [
    {
        id:"45", name:"TEST REPORT", partID:"4"
    },
    {
        id:"15", name:"01-077512", partID:"4"
    }];
};
```

Comment: The json key must match that which is typed into an input text field so as to get the array of objects within them.  So people will not type in `&quot;` into a text field, they will type in `"`.

Comment: and the `"` will be turned into `&quot;`. It is serializing the character. Which it does behind the scenes anyways when you work with JSON.

Comment: To test this, serialize a string with JsonConvert and it will turn it into the HTML character when you look at the result.

Comment: You're right, it works perfect, just did this:  `echo htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($partName), ENT_COMPAT)` on the value of the hidden input element and works like a charm.  Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it worked. You should be using HTML character codes in JSON anyways across the board. It is more compatible and parseable. Especially if the data was used in other ways.

Comment: So I should convert single quotes also?  Should I use `ENT_QUOTES` instead?

Comment: You don't need to convert single quotes, although some tools might. You can also just escape the JSON key `"Expando Sleeve 1/4\"" and put quotes around it. Although I prefer the character codes. A lot of tools will default to the character codes. If you're doing angle brackets or other html type characters it helps in my opinion to standardize everything.

Answer (score 1):

In chrome console all it's ok:

```
var obj = {};    
var val = "Expando Sleeve 1/4\"";
obj[val]="x";    
console.log(obj)
//console >> Object {Expando Sleeve 1/4": "x"}
```

another option:

```
var parts = {
    "Expando Sleeve 1/4\"": [
    {
        id:"45", name:"TEST REPORT", partID:"4"
    },
    {
        id:"15", name:"01-077512", partID:"4"
    }]
};    
console.log(parts)
//console >> 
//Object   Expando Sleeve 1/4": Array(2)
//__proto__    :    Object
```

Seems like jquery problem

**UPD:**
It's html-safety "problem", worked solution:

```
$('<input value="escape&quot"/>').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the character literal quote (') to save JSON keys as a string

```
var parts = {
    'Expando Sleeve 1/4"': [
    {
        id:"45", name:"TEST REPORT", partID:"4"
    },
    {
        id:"15", name:"01-077512", partID:"4"
    }]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace you double quote from value

```html
<input type="text" name="name" value="&quot;YOUR_VALUE">
```